# SAS - Putting non-numeric values on the X-AXIS of Histogram sgplot

Tags: sas, sgplot

I have a dataset called marks and I want to use `proc sgplot` to get the names of the students on the x axis and the marks of a1 on the y axis. I typed in histogram name, but apparently SAS doesn't let the x axis be non-numeric. Does anyone know if this is possible?

[image: want it to look like this pic -> click me]

Comment: Looking to the picture you shared of your data and plot, it seems that you want a bar plot, not a histogram.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, it will actually just be a vertical bar chart type of graph, not a histogram.  Histograms are plotted from many values per group.

So, the basic syntax will be:

```
title "a1 Marks by Student";
proc sgplot data=my_data;
  vbar Name / response=a1mark;
run;
title;
```